# TestFlight: Application executable contains unsupported architecture: armv7s

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, testflight

I'm trying to build an ad-hoc build with test flight.

I have the OS Device selected and am trying to create an archive.

However I get the following warning.

```
(null):  iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable contains unsupported 
 architecture(s): armv7s (-19031)
```

I have the following settings for my test flight target.

[image]

I can build fine for release.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying your question a bit? I'm not sure exactly what you're asking - do you want to get rid of the warning?

Comment: I think that warning is perfectly normal, please read my answer below and verify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using an old version of the TestFlight library.

The iPhone 5 uses a new processor (A6), with a modified instruction set (AMRv7s).
Since you are building your app with that architecture too, all linked libraries also needs to support it.

TestFlight provides a new version (1.1) of its library, with support for that specific architecture.
So simply download the new version of the library, link against that, and you'll be fine.

Your "Release" target is compiling and linking fine, because no symbol from the TestFlight library is actually used. But if you need TestFlight support for the iPhone 5, just update to the latest version of the library.

Comment: I did, although I copied over the a file rather than delete and re-add, will give that a go though, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This warning is perfectly normal when you use an armv7 device to archive your application.

Think about it, you make an archive that includes the armv7s architecture (which is what we want) and the warning tells you that your armv7 device does not support that architecture (which totally makes sense).

To prove that even further, just hook up an iPhone 5 and try archiving and you will see that the warning will go away.

Comment: When I hook up my iPhone5 (armv7s), the archive failed but if I pull out it. The archive work!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell Xcode 4.5 will not currently allow you to create Archive builds that include armv7s.

My project uses two 3rd party libraries (Dropbox and Flurry) and I reverified I had the latest iOS 6 builds included.  I verified that all my other frameworks (and libsqlite3.0.dylib) were all located in the iOS 6.0 area.  None of this helped.

I then created a brand new empty project from scratch and attempted an Archive build and received the exact same error.  So after wasting 6 hours trying to fix this, I am tentatively concluding it is not possible to get rid of the warning.

Based on comments else where, apparently, it is not necessary to build for armv7s to run on an iPhone 5.

Any information to the contrary of anything I have posted here would be appreciated.

Comment: That's correct. Also I did a clean / restart and the error went away

Comment: The error went away?  You were able to do an archive build with armv7s?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remove armv7s from the valid architectures.

Same question has been asked several ties I think.

Comment: I thought I needed that to support iphone 5 ?

Comment: Hmm... I have removed it from my project and I'm running on iPhone 5.  Maybe I didn't remove it (I'm sure I did though) can't check right now.  Sorry.

Comment: let me know what you find out.

Comment: Yes, I have a project that I have run on an iPhone 5 (it is running right now on my desk) and I have removed the armv7s from the valid architectures. Try it.  You can always put it back.

Answer (score -1):

I was displayed the same warning message when I archived in preparation for Ad-Hoc testing.

```
(null):  iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable contains unsupported 
 architecture(s): armv7s (-19031)
```

I have removed armv7s as recommended above and the warning went away. What repercussion are there in doing this? What is armv7s supporting?

With semingly no changes to any settings or code from yesterday, what may have caused this warning to pop up?

Comment: I can also solve this warning without removing armv7s if I set Build Active Architecture Only for Release to Yes. Though I am still unclear as to the reprocussions for either of these paths.